# how to display name and date within one drop down box in odoo

Tags: html, user-interface, odoo-8

I need to display name and the date in a drop down list to select a particular persons

example:

I have two persons with the same name 'Silpa'. When i am trying to select, both names will be displayed with in the drop down.So i need to display the date of birth of that person along with her name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `name_get` function

example:

```
def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    result= []
    if not all(ids):
        return result
    for pl in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        code = pl.seq
        name = pl.name.name
        name = '[%s] %s' % (code,name)
        result.append((pl.id,name))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function field like the following code.

Function Declaration

```
def _combine(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    values = {}
    #here cur_obj gets the value from the current object. 
    #But this could be the object in which you have saved your data.
    cur_obj=self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    code = cur_obj.name
    dob = cur_obj.dob
    for id in ids:
        rec = self.browse(cr, uid, [id], context=context)[0]
        values[id] = {}
        values[id] = '%s -- %s' % (code , dob)
    return values
```

Field Declaration

```
_columns = {
         'field_name': fields.function(_combine, type='selection'),
        }
```